# PySpark DataFrame - Number of "non-null clusters" per partition

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

First, let me start by providing a sample dataframe for illustration purposes. I have a dataframe with two columns. Below the code to create it:

```
df1_l = [
  (0, 1),
  (0, 2),
  (0, 3),
  (0, 4),
  (0, None),
  (0, None),
  (0, None),
  (0, 801),
  (0, 802),
  (0, 803),
  (0, None),
  (0, None),
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (1, 4),
  (1, None),
  (1, None),
  (1, None),
  (1, 801),
  (1, 802),
  (1, 803),
  (1, None),
  (1, None)
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1_l, schema = ["id", "val"])
df1.show()
```

The dataframe looks as follows:

```
+---+----+
| id| val|
+---+----+
|  0|   1|
|  0|   2|
|  0|   3|
|  0|   4|
|  0|null|
|  0|null|
|  0|null|
|  0| 801|
|  0| 802|
|  0| 803|
|  0|null|
|  0|null|
|  1|   1|
|  1|   2|
|  1|   3|
|  1|   4|
|  1|null|
|  1|null|
|  1|null|
|  1| 801|
+---+----+
```

- Column `id` is the column I use to partition several window functions.
- Column `val` is a column of values containing both nulls and numeric values.

**Goal**: I want to **count the number of non-null clusters** in the column **val** within each partition using a new column that gives the same integer value to all elements of a given cluster. A cluster is any set of consecutive rows with values different than `null` (1 isolated row different than null also constitutes a cluster).

In other words, the desired output would be the following (column `n_cluster`)

```
+---+----+---------+
| id| val|n_cluster|
+---+----+---------+
|  0|   1|        1|
|  0|   2|        1|
|  0|   3|        1|
|  0|   4|        1|
|  0|null|     null|
|  0|null|     null|
|  0|null|     null|
|  0| 801|        2|
|  0| 802|        2|
|  0| 803|        2|
|  0|null|     null|
|  0|null|     null|
|  1|   1|        1|
|  1|   2|        1|
|  1|   3|        1|
|  1|   4|        1|
|  1|null|     null|
|  1|null|     null|
|  1|null|     null|
|  1| 801|        2|
+---+----+---------+
```

**Could somebody help me create the column n_cluster?**.

NOTE: the above is just a toy example. Each partition can have a number of clusters greater than 2. The column "n_cols" shall number them as clarified in the example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below a code that achieves just what I intended and a call to that function using the sample data:

```
def cluster_ids(df_data: DataFrame, 
                partition_by: List[str],
                val_column: str,
                ts_column: str) -> DataFrame:

  cumsum_column = "cumsum"
  window_cumsum = (
                    Window.partitionBy(*partition_by)
                          .orderBy(F.asc(ts_column))
                          .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
                  )

  window_rows = (
              Window.partitionBy(*partition_by)
                    .orderBy(F.asc(cumsum_column))
              )

  marker = func.when(func.col(val_column).isNull(), 1).otherwise(0)
  cumsum = F.sum(marker).over(window_cumsum)

  df_data_cumsum = df_data.withColumn(cumsum_column, cumsum)
  df_cluster_ids = (df_data_cumsum
                          .filter(func.col(val_column).isNotNull())
                          .select(*partition_by, cumsum_column).dropDuplicates()
                          .withColumn("cluster_id", func.row_number().over(window_rows))
                   )
  
  result = (df_data_cumsum.join(df_cluster_ids,
                               on = [*partition_by, cumsum_column],
                               how = "left")
                          .withColumn("cluster_id", 
                                      func.when(func.col("val").isNotNull(), func.col("cluster_id")))
                          .drop(cumsum_column)
           )

  return result

res = cluster_ids(df_data = df1,
                  partition_by = ["id"],
                  ts_column = "row",
                  val_column = "val")
```